# Format email message in Django

Tags: python, django, django-email

I'm trying to send email message in one of my views and would like to format the body of the message, such that it shows in different lines.

This is a snippet code in `views.py`:

```
  body = "Patient Name: " +  patient_name + \
                   "Contact: " + phone + \
                   "Doctor Requested: Dr. " +  doctor.name + \
                   "Preference: " + preference

  email = EmailMessage('New Appointment Request', body, to=['ex@gmail.com'])
  email.send()
```

The email is shown like this:

```
Patient Name: AfrojackContact: 6567892Doctor Requested: Dr. IrenaPreference: Afternoon
```

How do I make it show like this:

```
Patient Name: Afrojack

Contact: 6567892

Doctor Requested: Dr. Irena

Preference: Afternoon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going right but you just missed a letter `n`

```
body = "Patient Name: " +  patient_name + "\n"
                   + "Contact: " + phone + "\n"
                   + "Doctor Requested: Dr. " +  doctor.name + "\n"
                   + "Preference: " + preference
```

This will add new line after each and every line and most probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use the django template system to do that.

You could do:

````
```
from django.template import loader, Context

def send_templated_email(subject, email_template_name, context_dict, recipients):


    template = loader.get_template(email_template_name)

    context = Context(context_dict)

    email = EmailMessage(subject, body, to=recipients)
    email.send()

```
````

The template will look like: this could for example be in the file `myapp/templates/myapp/email/doctor_appointment.email`:

````
```

Patient Name: {{patient_name}}

Contact: {{contact_number}}

Doctor Requested: {{doctor_name}}

Preference: {{preference}}
```
````

and you will use it like

````
```
context_email = {"patient_name" : patient_name,
    "contact_number" : phone,
    "doctor_name":  doctor.name,
    "preference" :  preference}

send_templated_email("New Appointment Request", 
                     "myapp/templates/myapp/email/doctor_appointment.email",
                     context_email, 
                     ['ex@gmail.com'])
```
````

This is very powerfull, because you can style all the email in the way you want,
and you re-use the same function over and over, just need to create new template 
and pass appropriate context/subject and recipietns

Comment: This seems like it could be very helpful but I think it is missing a few items for the first snippet. Could you please add: which file this is saved in, the import for EmailMessage(), the line where you set the value for body, and how you are using context? I also thing the doctor_appointment.email should be doctor_appointment.html. Please let me know if I'm wrong on any of that. This is a great answer would love to use this approach. I need to format my messages with html before sending.

Answer (score 3):

you should add '\n' for newlines.

or you could try this:

```
body = '''Patient Name: {}
Contact: {}
Doctor Requested: Dr. {}
Preference: {}'''.format(patient_name, phone, doctor.name, preference)
```

or, if you are using python >= 3.6:

```
body = f'''Patient Name: {patient_name}
Contact: {phone}
Doctor Requested: Dr. {doctor.name}
Preference: {preference}'''
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick for breakline:

```
\n
```